# Ruby/Thor exit status in case of an error

Tags: ruby, thor

I'm new to Thor (and to Ruby) and I'm considering using it within a build script, as it's said it can be a replacement to Rake (thus to Make).
However after a short trial, I'm confused about the error status it returns. I quickly went through the wiki but haven't seen any mention about that.

With just the first "Simple Example", `test.thor`:

```
class Test < Thor
  desc "example", "an example task"
  def example
    puts "I'm a thor task!"
  end
end
```

version #:

```
eruve>thor version
Thor 0.18.1
```

I tried the following, an erroneous command on purpose:

```
eruve>ruby --version; thor test:example badarg; echo exit status: $?

ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
ERROR: thor example was called with arguments ["badarg"]
Usage: "thor test:example".
exit status: 0
```

So, there was an error but it exits with status 0 nonetheless... meaning I'd rather not use it in a (non-ruby) script, or else the script would continue running even though it should terminate. Subsequent errors might be difficult to analyse.

I must be missing something, hence my questions:

- Is there an easy way to get a non-zero status by default in case of an error (config file, etc.)?
- If not, what am I supposed to do to get it right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on bundler's solution (many thanks @fontno), and more investigation on my side, here is a hack in order to have it working with a normal shell. WARNING: it's not elegant, prints out the exception stack crap, but I think that works (please don't hesitate to tell me otherwise).

```
class Thorough < Thor
  ENV["THOR_DEBUG"] = "1"
  check_unknown_options!
private
  def subcommand(*_) super subcommand(*_)
  rescue Thor::Error => e
    $stderr.puts e.message
    exit 1
  end
end

class Test < Thor#ough
  desc "example", "an example task"
  def example
    puts "I'm a thor task!"
  end
end
```

Written as above, it has the same behavior as before (I believe). Now, after removing the `#` from `Thor#ough`, it should exit with status 1 if Thor has raised an `Error`, thus allowing some control from e.g. a non-ruby shell.

```
eruve>thor test:example badarg; echo $?
/Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:482:in `handle_argument_error': ERROR: thor example was called with arguments ["badarg"] (Thor::InvocationError)
Usage: "thor test:example".
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:35:in `rescue in run'
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:21:in `run'
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/runner.rb:36:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:29:in `run'
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:128:in `run'
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/thor-0.18.1/bin/thor:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/thor:23:in `load'
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/thor:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/eruve/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
1

eruve>thor test:example; echo $?
I'm a thor task!
0

eruve>thor test:example badarg 2>/dev/null; echo $?
1
```

Cheers.
PS: I wonder, are there many gotchas like this in Thor? If it's an expected behavior, its purpose/philosophy is incompatible with the needs of my project... hacks are not a reliable solution.

Answer (score 24):

I know this has been answered already but I think this is a better answer so I thought I'd contribute it anyway.

Thor has a method you can use to change the behavior so errors cause non-zero exit codes. It's not documented very well (IMHO).

```
class Test < Thor
  def self.exit_on_failure?
    true
  end

  desc "example", "an example task"
  def example
    puts "I'm a thor task!"
  end
end
```

The default for this is inexplicably `false`. I don't know why anyone would want it to behave like that personally. [Thor issue 244](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/issues/244) addresses this as well.

Update:
As of Thor 1.0.0, you will get a [deprecation warning](https://github.com/rails/thor/blob/v1.0.0/lib/thor/base.rb#L521) if you do *not* provide your own `exit_on_failure?` method. This was to deal with the confusing default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I also noticed this when looking a `thor` to use for a project. As far as I can tell this is expected behavior. This [pull request for `bundler`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/2478) has an interesting solution that may be appropriate for you.

They enabled the thor debug flag so they could catch the error and set the appropriate exit status

```
# bin/bundle

Bundler.with_friendly_errors {
    # Set debug flag so we can rescue Thor::error's
    # and set the correct exit code.
    ENV["THOR_DEBUG"] = "1"
    Bundler::CLI.start
}


# friendly_errors

rescue Thor::UndefinedCommandError => e
    Bundler.ui.error e.message
    exit 15
  rescue Thor::Error => e
    Bundler.ui.error e.message
    exit 1
```

Comment: +1 because it led to a hack (see my answer), although that's not directly usable, in particular as a solution outside of Ruby.